# how to deploy existant apache sling repository on tomcat?

Tags: apache, tomcat, jackrabbit, jcr, sling

I have a sling repository and I'm using sling luanchpad 6.0 jar to startup the sling instance.
How can I deploy this sling instance -containing application, contents and bundles- on an apache tomcat?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Use the Sling launchpad war file instead of the jar file.

Comment: BTW: What is the point of deploying sling within tomcat? After all, it already contains the OSGI container felix to manage your deployments, and the servlet engine jetty. http://stackoverflow.com/q/17277405/21499

Comment: This is now discussed at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17277405/advantages-of-deploying-sling-jackrabbit-on-tomcat